# Как сравнить три значения в си?

Tags: c, сравнение, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, придумать алгоритм. Или киньте кусочек кода на си. Задача:

> Как сравнить три числа(числовые значения переменных) и найти наименьшее из них, и делать то то и т.д.?

Просто, не хочу писать большой код, думаю наверняка есть короткий алгоритм.

Спасибо.

Ps [@ХэшКод](/users/1/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), расширьте, пожалуйста,лимит комментариев в данном посте.

Comment: int a, b, c; a = min(a, b); a = min(a, c); тогда в а храниться наименьшее число

Comment: @Janycz, не понял Вас. Сделать отдельную функцию для сравнения или что?

Comment: Аноним, аргументируй свйо минус за топик.

Comment: Если а, b, c - числа для сравнения, тогда: a = min(a, b); a = min(a, c); в результате в а храниться наименьшее число

Comment: @ВладиславМСК минус я вам поставил за то, что  должно быть стыдно стыдно задавать настолько простые вопросы, особенно учитыая тот факт, что судя по вашим многочисленным вопросам и большому сроку пребывания на этом форуме, Си  - язык для вас явно не новый. Так что уж не обессудьте

Comment: @DreamChild, вы правы, спасибо. Но на даннай момент это для меня реальная проблема. Писать 10 if else не хочу, я же не индусский программист. Я просто хочу одино момент уточнить, потому что в математической модели, которую я сейчас пишу, мне нужно сравнить 9 переменных. Просто я немного переработал алгоритм, и теперь нужно сравнить 3, а потом ещё раз 3 перменные(не из массива!!!).
Вот и не знаю, как нормальный код написать. Вы бы лучше идею подкинули.

Comment: @Janycz, min это что?

Comment: Продолжение комментариев.
@DreamChild, Комментарии опять закончились, пишу тут.
В зависимости от того, какая из 3-я переменных меньше, выполнять дальнейшие указания(у меня это большие математические расчёты, которые разделены по функциям.)

@avp, мне нужно именно то, о чём вы говорите. 

Comment: @DreamChild, я так и не понял, о чём вы говорите. Я просто не догоняю, что нужно сделать.

На SO был подобный вопрос, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472249/homework-help-max-and-min-value-with-if-statements, и очень красиво реализован. Вы подразумевали это? Я буду использовать этот код.

Comment: >я так и не понял, о чём вы говорите. Я просто не догоняю, что нужно сделать

@ВладиславМСК блин вы прикалываетесь что ли? Вы хотите сказать, что не знаете, что такое функция или что такое макрос?

Comment: Я знаю, что такое функция и макрос. Но я не понимаю алгоритм, который Вы мне говорите. Я сейчас вывожу в отдельную функцию код со SO. Правда выходит очень некрасиво и малопонятно. Для определения, получается, я использую 3 if else + switch case. Как напишу, кину код.

Comment: ну так если знаете, что такое функция, то возьмите и напишите эту самую функцию для определения минимального значения из двух чисел, а потом используйте ее. В чем сложность-то? Элементарно ведь. Зачем тут какие-то switch-case?

Comment: @DreamChild, мой код не сработал. Видимо я безнадёжен :/.
<code>
...
double test(double a, double b, double c)
{
 double min, max;
 max = a;
 min = b;

 if(a< b)
 {
  min = a;
  max = b;
 }
 if(c< min)
 {
  min = c;
 }
 if(c> max)
 {
  max = c;
 }

 return min;
}
...

while (1)
 {
  switch (test(z[0],z[1],z[2]))
  {
  case z[0]: break;
  case z[1]: break;
  case z[2]: break;
  default: break;
  }
 }

</code>

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК  чаму такие ужасы? Напишите проще:

    int min(int x, int y)
    {
        return x < y ? x : y;
    }
    
    // =====
    
    int a = 3, b = 7, c = 2;
    int minValue = min(a, min(b, c)); // minValue == 2

Либо можете через макрос: 

    #define min(a, b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))

Comment: @DreamChild, ок, а для трёх переменных, выполнять всё это дважды?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК что вы хотите сделать с тремя переменными?

Comment: @DreamChild, мне почему-то кажется, что ТС нужна не величина минимума, а именно переменная, значением которой является этот минимум. И в зависимости от того, это a, b или c он будет выполнять разный код.

А вот просто найти минимум (например, записав a,b,c в массив) и потом написать что-то вроде

     if (vmin == a) {
       ...
     else if (vmin == b) {
       ...
     else {
       ...
     }

он почему-то не хочет.

Иначе я не могу осознать, чего ему до сих пор не понятно.

Впрочем, может ему все же удастся все толково объяснить.

Comment: min - функция из stdlib.h, возвращает меньший аргумент.

Comment: @Janycz, это в какой системе в `stdlib.h` min() определен?

В Linux (`Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`) и gcc и g++ так не считают.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, просто вместо комментария пишите **Update** в вопросе.

А что, Вы еще не нашли этот минимум?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = 5, b = 2, c = 8;
    cout << min(min(a, b), c) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = 5, b = 2, c = 8;
    printf("%d\n", min(a, min(b, c)));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если интересует не сам минимум, а *переменная* (адрес) содержащая  минимальное значение, то можно вот так

```
int *
pimin (int *pa, int *pb, int *pc)
{
  int m, *pm;

  if (*pa <= *pb) {
    m = *pa; pm = pa;
  } else {
    m = *pb; pm = pb;
  }

  return (m > *pc) ? pc : pm;
}
```

Если в `main` написать что-то такое

```
  struct x {
    int v;
    const char *name;
  };
  struct x a, b, c, *r;

  ....

  int *pres = pimin(&a.v, &b.v, &c.v);
  ....
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
        ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))

  r = list_entry(pres, struct x, v);
  printf ("min = %d (%s)\n", *pres, r->name);
```

то можно получить:

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 4 13 21
min = 4 (a)
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 4 13 2
min = 2 (c)
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Может Вы имели в виду такой подход?

Comment: @avp, Примерно такой, только бюез использования динамической памяти. Вы правы, мне нужна именно минимальная переменная. Я это всё сделал с помощью ответа выше, а для того, что бы понять, что это за переменная(потому что в зависимости от переменной нужны разные действия), сделал это через 3 условия, а не через адрес. Честно говоря ваш подход через адрес не совсем понял. Сейчас думаю над ним.

Comment: Можно ведь проще или Я ошибаюсь?

    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int* min(int* x, int* y)
    {
     return (*x) < (*y) ? x:y;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
     int a = 5, b = 17, c = 8;
     int* min_value = min(min(&a, &b), &c);
     
     printf("Min value: %d;\nAddress: %d\n", *min_value, min_value);
     return 0;
    }

Comment: @uzumaxy, конечно, можно. 

Просто `min(min(a,b),c)` тут уже в разных комментариях писали раза 3. Подумал, что ТС м.б. хочет в одной функции.

--

@ВладиславМСК, в этой программе нет динамической памяти. Просто указатели (впрочем, указывать на динамическую память тоже можно).

Comment: @avp, видели мой комментарий с кодом switch-case? Я заменил конструкцию switch на if else. Может это страшно, но мне нравиться. Я просто сам догоняю этот код. А остальной не очень :).
С вашей точки зрения это нормальный вариант или убожество?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, главное, чтобы Вам самому было понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Охосспадя, для такой задачи и таких монстров понаписали, со структурами да с указателями...

```
int min = (a < b)? ((a < c)? a : c) : ((b < c)? b : c);
```